# How to convert oracle number type to string with format?

Tags: string, oracle, numbers, format, converters

I want to convert number type to string with format as:

```
number -> string

    1      -> 001
    2      -> 002
    12     -> 012
    340    -> 340
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use either [TO_CHAR()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions199.htm#i1006717) (preferable in this situation) function or [LPAD()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions095.htm#i1371196) function to achieve the desired result:

```
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select 1   from dual union all
  3    select 2   from dual union all
  4    select 12  from dual union all
  5    select 340 from dual
  6  )
  7  select to_char(col, '000')        as num_1
  8       , lpad(to_char(col), 3, '0') as num_2
  9    from t1
 10  ;

NUM_1 NUM_2
----- ------------
 001  001
 002  002
 012  012
 340  340
```